# Rearranging forumlas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I rearrange this formulae?

I need to make $x$ the subject.

$a)\ \ $ $k = \pi(x - t)$

I think it involves factorising but I'm not sure, I tried dividing the $(x - t)$ from both sides to get:

$\dfrac{k}{x - t} = \pi$ clause but then I'm stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: By $PIE,$ do you mean $\pi$, or is it $P \times I \times E$ (or, perhaps, the delicious food)?

Comment: It would be better, if you would first divide the equation by $\pi$. After that you can add t on both sides.

Comment: I meant the mathematics pie :).

Comment: @PerfectNutter Just for future reference, $\pi$ is spelled "pi" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by $PIE$, then you get $x-t = \frac{k}{PIE}$, from which you add $t$ to both sides to get an expression for $x$.

Answer (score 3):

First you can divide $\pi$ to the lefthand side:

$$\dfrac{k}{\pi} = x - t$$

Then you simply add $t$:

$$\dfrac{k}{\pi} + t = x$$

So therefore $x = \dfrac{k}{\pi}+t$

Answer (score 2):

$$k=\pi(x-t)=\pi x-\pi t \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \pi x=\pi t+k \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=\frac{\pi t+k}{\pi} = t+\frac{k}{\pi}$$